# websocket and Isolate.spawnuri

Tags: dart, websocket, dart-isolates

Is it possible to use websockets form within a Dart isolate created with `Isolate.spawnuri` ?

My understanding is that, client side, `Isolate.spawnuri` use WebWorkers and that WebWorker can't use `dart:html` (DOM) but, client side, websockets are part of `dart:html`. so it's a no go?

thx

(it's hard to test, I get no error or info when trying to do this with the Dart Editor, the spawned isolate is invisible and throw no visible error, it just hangs)

here some code to test this: https://gist.github.com/kgersen/148460d056f498a849ef

Comment: Your isolate appears to hang because you are not catching the object that is thrown when you instantiate a WebSocket. You must catch all thrown objects within the isolate's main() else the isolate will suspend or terminate. If you want to see the error information you must send it back to the main isolate through a SendPort. My testing indicates that use of some classes within an spawnuri created isolate results in a thrown UnimplementedError, but use if the DOM including instantiating a WebSocket throws a String (SDK 1.6).

Comment: yeah addind a catch gives:
DOM access is not enabled in this isolate

Answer (score 2):

This is work in progress. The will be an `isolate.spawnDomXxxx` which allows to import `dart:html`. See http://dartbug.com/3050

Comment: yes but it's in 'triaged' state since 2012. is this really a WIP?

Comment: There wasn't much progress with isolates for a long time but in my experience the last months isolates made good progress (monitoring http://dartbug.com updates). Support for breakpoints in isolates was implemented very recently, different methods for handling errors, notification about ended isolates, ...

Comment: tx i'll keep an eye that one then.

Comment: on 2nd thought, why WebSocket is in dart:html instead of having its own package (dart:websocket for instance) ?

Comment: In the browser you have only functionality available that the browsers API provides. `dart:html` is just an abstraction of this API and in addition tries to provide an unified API where browser differences are hidden.

Comment: yeah but WebSocket are not browser specific, there is even a different version in dart:io for server. They need to unify these 2, at least at some higher level like they did with Isolate: it has its own package (dart:async) but when running inside a browser it uses webworker and when running server side it uses something else (probably some fork()).
They could do the same with WebSocket.

Comment: on 3rd thought (:)), I should 1st check if websocket works within a webworker when using JS only and not Dart. The bottom line is what browsers can actually do. no point wanting Dart to do something if underneath browsers cant run it.

Comment: On the server a package can make use of every OS feature using for example native extensions. In the browser you can only use what the browser provides. The point is not that `WebSocket` is not browser specific but that the browser provides an API for WebSockets and this is the only way you can use them. You get access to this browser API by importing `dart:html`.
The problem with client side isolates is, that you then have two or more isolates which can access the DOM concurrently which easily leads to race condition. WebWorkers is only used when compiled to JS as far as I know.

Comment: I agree, but the problem is that all browser APIs are now in a single package (dart:html) making all of them 'no go' for multithreading because only some part of them may lead to race condition.
Ideally splitting dart:html into 2 packages: one thread-safe and one not thread-safe could be a solution (but not an elegant one I admit)

Comment: Similar discussions were going on on some related issues. There are many dependencies, as far as I know this is one of the reasons why it takes so long.